# 'gtk/gtk.h' file not found Even with pkg-config

Tags: c, linux, makefile, gtk, gtk3

I'm creating a software in C using the SDL library and GTK+3. My first attempt with GTK+3 on a specific main.c and its Makefile works well, but when I try to add my GTK project to the other piece of code using my "real" Makefile, even if I added the same flags for GTK+3, I can't compile and get the `gtk/gtk.h file no found` error. I visited many threads about this error but I still can't make it work.

Here's my old Makefile, making things work:

```
CC=clang
CPPFLAGS= `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`
CFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -O2
LDFLAGS=
LDLIBS= `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config gmodule-2.0 --libs`
SRC= main.c
OBJ= ${SRC:.c=.o}
all: main
main: ${OBJ} -lm
clean:
rm -f *~ *.o main
```

And here's the one I use for the project:

```
CC=clang

CPPFLAGS= `pkg-config --cflags sdl gtk+-3.0`
CFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c99 -O2 -pedantic
LDFLAGS=
LDLIBS= `pkg-config --libs sdl` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config  gmodule-2.0 --libs` -lgtk -lgdk -lglib -lX11 -lXext -lSDL -lSDL_image -lm

SRCDIR   = src
OBJDIR   = obj
BINDIR   = bin

TARGET = main

SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
INCLUDES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.h)
DEPENDS  := $(wildcard $(OBJDIR)/*.d)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
rm       = rm -f

all: makedirs $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
@$(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
@echo "Linking complete!"

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
@$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
@echo "[OK] Compiled "$<""

makedirs:
@mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
@mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
@echo "[OK] Created directories : $(BINDIR) $(OBJDIR)"
[....] etc
```

And the error:

```
src/main.c:2:14: fatal error: 'gtk/gtk.h' file not found
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

Tanks for the attention :)

[EDIT]

```
~                                                                              
  ▶ pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
  -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 

  ~                                                                              
  ▶ pkg-config --cflags sdl gtk+-3.0
  -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT -pthread -I/usr/include/SDL -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
```

And the header of main.c:

```
  #include <gtk/gtk.h>    
  #include <stdio.h>    
  #include <stdlib.h>     
  #include "neural.h"
```

Comment: I edited my question, thanks ;)

Comment: I have debian, and everyhing is installed, also when I use the first Makefile I can compile and run the test software that includes gtk/gtk.h

Comment: It's only my main software using SDL and other stuff that causes troubles, my biggest Makefile must be wrong somewhere I guess, but I cannot find where

Comment: If your first makefile works, then yes you should have the header file installed. Y. Verzun's answer below will probably correct your second makefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply forgot to add CPPFLAGS to the rule $(OBJECTS)

It should look like:

```
$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o :
```

`$(SRCDIR)/%.c@$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@`

`@echo "[OK] Compiled "$<""`

Answer (score 5):

As Y. Verzun said, I forgot to add the CPPFLAGS rule, but not only to the OBJECTS:

```
$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
@$(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDLIBS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@
@echo "Linking complete!"

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
@$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
@echo "[OK] Compiled "$<""
```

here's the code working, notice both of the $(CPPFLAGS) added.
Thanks a lot !